# commas are not being joined with a space after them jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a space after a comma for each string in an array with jQuery. I managed to retain non unique values from repeating themselves but I am now faced with the commas not having a space after them even though I have used the join method. Here is my code:

```
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];

    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) {
            result.join(", ");
            result.push(e);
        } 
    });

    // sort the elements
    result.sort();

    return result;
}

$('#filetext').text(function(i, original) {
    var rfile = path.split('/').pop() + ',' + original;

    rfile = rfile.replace(/,+$/, "");

    // split the files by a comma 
    var arr = rfile.split(',');

    return unique(arr);
});
```

The result however is string1,string2 and I would like to get it to be string1, string2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Updated function code -

```
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];

    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) {
            result.push(e);
        } 
    });

    // sort and join the elements
    result.sort();

    return result.join(", ");
}
```

Comment: Just dd a space after the comma.

Comment: I have. result.join(", ");

Comment: `result.join(", ");` does nothing in your code.... It returns a string....

Comment: okay.... well how then would I do this?

Comment: Use join at the return line, not in the middle of a loop.

Comment: but if I do that, repeating values are allowed, which I do not want.. and it does not get sorted.

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Comment: yes I just did @epascarello

Comment: Than you did something other than remove the join() line and move it to the return line.

Comment: I took it out of the .each loop, that is all.

Comment: `result.sort(); return result.join(", "); }`

Comment: check out the updated code I just posted for the function @epascarello

Comment: So are you sure it is not the inArray check that is failing to get dupes since the join() line has nothing to do with that check.

Comment: it is getting duplicate values after changing.

Comment: Well the join() is not going to produce dupes. So I have no clue where your problem is. It just combines what is in the array.

Comment: but if i only return result it does not get duplicate values

Comment: When does it return dupe values? Do you account for the added whitespace when you check for dupes?

Comment: it returns duplicate values only when i use return result.join(", ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on convo in comments, trim the text, return with the join()

```
function unique(list) {
    var result = [];

    $.each(list, function(i, e) {
        var txt = $.trim(e);
        if ($.inArray(txt, result) == -1) {
            result.push(e);
        } 
    });

    // sort and join the elements
    result.sort();

    return result.join(", ");
}
```

or change your split to handle the whitespace.

```
rfile.split(/\s*,\s*/g);
```

Comment: I am sort is sorting the strings how strings are sorted. Sounds like you should be making a new question with that problem.

Comment: like if I click on an two elements it does but if i click on a previously one it puts the one behind the other one (i.e. not alphabetically)